# WebsiteSpark & Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, bizspark, websitespark

Having a look around at [WebsiteSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/web/websitespark/Default.aspx) from Microsoft - the deal is good (especially if you were looking to go down this path already). But I'm one of those people that likes to 'wait for the next version' if I'm in no rush to sign up. One question that's been bugging me is whether or not the program includes upgrades to Visual Studio and/or they will change the starting pack at some point?

Currently, If you sign up now, you get 3 copies of Visual Studio 2008.

If you're umming and ahhing about the scheme, is it worth waiting and hoping that they adapt their program so that it comes with VS2010? Or maybe that they'll offer free updates to those already in the scheme?

(This question may be a little subjective I guess and it probably applies to the BizSpark side of things as well. Have there been any hints set in other Microsoft programs that might indicate the outcome? ).

Comment: They have an exit clause. So you should be aware of that.

Comment: It's a "possible" $100 exit fee like bizspark isn't it? Hardly worth worrying about!

Comment: $100 is the only catch and like you said , thats nothing for what your receiving

Comment: The $100 fee has been waived for WebSiteSpark

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See Scott's answer here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/24/announcing-the-websitespark-program.aspx

> This is great. Will is cover software upgrades i.e. VS 2010 when
>   available?
>
> Yes - while you are in the program you
>   can always download the latest version
>   of any of the software. So once VS
>   2010 is released you can download that
>   as well.
>
> Hope this helps,
>
> Scott

Comment: Brilliant, I missed that :) Thanks

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear the news.

Answer (score 2):

Scott gu confirmed on his blog that the liceses will cover 2010 when it's released.